make dynamic checkmark sign in python
I would like to apply little project, where color of checkmark  changes according condition, let us consider following schreenshot :

definitely i change color of check mark  from span tag right? but let us suppose i would like to make it  depend on some conditions and  i would like to use python for it, namely flask,let us consider following  form :

so user is entering his age and weight and if both of  them  satisfies some condition, then   color of checkmark must be  green else  it  must be red, i know that checkmark sign is this :
<span style="color: rgb(0,255,0);">&#10003 </span><br>
but how to make  it dynamic? i have tried following  one :i have created text_color variable in python  : color_text = "color: rgb(255,255,0);"  and  apply it in html file  like this :
&#10003 
but  does not  affect it directly , so how  can i do it  better? please help  me, i will post html and python codes :
python code :
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("Ages.html")


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
# @app.route('/')
def predict():
    text = [x for x in request.form.values()]
    age = float(text[0])
    weight = float(text[1])
    if age > 18 and weight > 70:
        Text = f"your age is {age} and your  weight is {weight}"
    else:
        Text = f"sorry your age  and weight does not meet  condtions"
    color_text = "color: rgb(255,255,0);"
    # text=list(text)
    return render_template("Ages.html", prediction_text=Text)
    # sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
    # result =sentiment_pipeline(text)[0]
    # if result['label']=='POSITIVE':
    #     return render_template('Commenting.html',prediction_text=f'emotion of comment is positive')
    # else:
    #     return render_template('Commenting.html', prediction_text=f'emotion of comment is not positive')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()


html code :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Enter Your Age</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Enter your Age and Weight</p>

  <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="post">
    <label for="age">enter your age:</label><br><span style={{color_text}}>&#10003 </span><br>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" value=""><br>
    <label for="weight">Enter your weight:</label><br><span style={{color_text}}>&#10003 </span><br>
    <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <h4 style="color:Violet;">
    {{ prediction_text }}
  </h4>

</body>

</html>


There are 2 ways to achieve validation in forms:

simple html validation, no request is necessary
backend validation, an ajax request is necessary

Depending on your requirements, whether your validation is a complex one or a simple one (in your example I don't see any complicated logic to use an ajax request), you will incorporate one or both methods into your forms.
The simple example:


const ageInput = document.getElementById("age");
const checkmark = document.querySelector(".checkmark");

ageInput.addEventListener("input", function () {
  if (this.value >= 18 && this.value <= 100) {
    checkmark.style.color = "green";
  } else {
    checkmark.style.color = "red";
  }
});
<h1>Enter age</h1>
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" id="age" required>
    <span class="checkmark" style="color: red;">&#10003;</span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



The complex example will require you to write a validation view and instead of using render_template, you need to return a json response. You need to handle it accordingly afterwards. (Flask serializes dictionaries into json.)
@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    # some validation steps
    return {"success": True}


thank you, first part of code should be added in html   right?
